# MVC3 Content->Site.css Where can I find some templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

Are there any templates to replace site.css without having to change to HTML markup of the default _layout in MVC 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [MvcContrib Template Gallery](http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/) with a growing list of templates you can apply to your default mvc applications